# Error occurred during the integration of CnosDB with Telegraf

Tags: cnosdb

/opt/homebrew/etc/telegraf.conf：

```
  [[inputs.tail]]
  files = ["/var/log/cnosdb/data_node.2001.log", "/var/log/cnosdb/data_node.2001.log"]
  from_beginning = true
  data_format = "grok"
  watch_method = "FSEvents"
  name_override = "syslog"
  grok_patterns = ['%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{DATA:module}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}']



 [[outputs.http]]
 url = "http://127.0.0.1:8902/api/v1/write?db=telegraf_log"
 timeout = "5s"
 method = "POST"
 username = "root"
 password = ""
 data_format = "influx"
 use_batch_format = true
 content_encoding = "identity"
 idle_conn_timeout = 10
```

Error occurred while running telegraf:

```
2023-09-20T18:20:02.507122872+08:00  INFO meta::store::state_machine: METADATA WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":21808443392,"time":1695205202,"status":"Healthy"}
2023-09-20T18:20:31.018607857+08:00 ERROR cnosdb::http::http_service: Failed to handle http sql request, err: Query: Datafusion: Error during planning: Table not found, tenant: cnosdb db: cnosdb_admin_stats, table: cpu
2023-09-20T18:20:31.027309873+08:00 ERROR cnosdb::http::http_service: Failed to handle http sql request, err: Query: Datafusion: Error during planning: Table not found, tenant: cnosdb db: cnosdb_admin_stats, table: cpu
2023-09-20T18:20:31.028062160+08:00 ERROR cnosdb::http::http_service: Failed to handle http sql request, err: Query: Datafusion: Error during planning: Table not found, tenant: cnosdb db: cnosdb_admin_stats, table: cpu
2023-09-20T18:20:32.507520717+08:00  INFO meta::store::state_machine: METADATA WRITE: /data_version :75
```

Has anyone encountered this situation?